# Needing help passing JSON data to CSV file in PHP

Tags: php, json, csv

Good afternoon, I have to take some data from JSON and export it to a CSV file inside the electronicCards folder.
I've done a script but it don't works, it throws an error that says "PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/uicBackendTest/toCSV.php on line 8"

If somebody can help me, I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance.
[image: code screenshot]

first edit:
php code:

```php
$jsonDecoded = json_decode("db/user.json", true);
$csvFileName = 'users.csv';

$fp = fopen($csvFileName, 'w');

foreach($jsonDecoded as $student) {
    fputcsv($fp, $student);
}

fclose($fp);
```

```
[
    {
       "_id":"5d66cc125ff627758284c85f",
       "isActive":true,
       "age":27,
       "name":{
          "first":"Diana",
          "last":"Key"
       },
       "email":"Diana.Key@uic.es",
       "phone":"+1 (846) 497-2375",
       "address":"773 Elton Street, Avalon, Alaska, 5634"
    },
    {
       "_id":"5d66cc12484e522f8cce4d34",
       "isActive":true,
       "age":36,
       "name":{
          "first":"Lucinda",
          "last":"Winters"
       },
       "email":"Lucinda.Winters@uic.es",
       "phone":"+1 (875) 582-3295",
       "address":"117 Essex Street, Fredericktown, New York, 7874"
    }
]
```

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It's done, the json code are the two first students, but there are some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

> json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = FALSE [, int $depth = 512
>   [, int $options = 0 ]]] ) : mixed
>
> **json**
>
> The json string being decoded.

So you are trying to decode the file name, you need to read the file before decoding it...

```
$jsonDecoded = json_decode(file_get_contents("db/user.json"), true);
```

Comment: It worked fine! Mea Culpa for not reading all the documentation. A lot of thanks.